# How to read the table from the word document and make proper dataframe structure?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, document

I have table in word document in unstructured format. I need to read the table start from 3 row and make the proper dataframe.[image]

Expected output :

```
   Rows start   day1   day2   day3   day4   day5   day6
0           1  test1  test2  test3  test4  test5  test6
1           2  test1  test2  test3  test4  test5  test6
2           3  test1  test2  test3  test4  test5  test6
3           4  test1  test2  test3  test4  test5  test6
4           5  test1  test2  test3  test4  test5  test6
```

I have tried this code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from docx import Document
key = Document("input1.docx")

for i, row in enumerate(key_table.rows):
    text = (cell.text for cell in row.cells)

    if i == 0:
        keys = tuple(text)
        continue
    row_data = dict(zip(keys, text))
    data.append(row_data)
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

but it return wrong struture.
Testing data : https://docs.google.com/document/d/1MCbckKdBIapx4QO9v4LjRELVdUwveA0LQMPR27MfMho/edit?usp=drivesdk
Thanks advance.

Comment: Can you expand your example so that you demonstrate how you're getting your word document table into your python program?

Comment: I used Document lib for reading the document
from docx import Document
key = Document("input1.docx")
key_table = key.tables[0]

Comment: Please show us in your question :) Including `import` statements too!

Comment: I have updated my questions i need a expected output.

Comment: Is the table in your docx file a Table or an image of a Table?

Comment: difficult to answer without having an actual example of such file

Comment: @itprorh66 yes it's table. I just take the screenshot and upload here.

Comment: @mozway you can use this link to read get the test data.https://docs.google.com/document/d/1MCbckKdBIapx4QO9v4LjRELVdUwveA0LQMPR27MfMho/edit?usp=drivesdk

Answer (score 0):

Try as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
from docx import Document

doc = Document('input1.docx')

table = doc.tables[0]
start_row = 2 # row that should become the column names
data = [[cell.text for cell in row.cells] for i, row in enumerate(table.rows) 
        if i >= start_row]
df = pd.DataFrame(data[1:], columns=data[0])

print(df)

  Rows start   day1   day2   day3   day4   day5   day6
0          1  test1  test2  test3  test4  test5  test6
1          2  test1  test2  test3  test4  test5  test6
2          3  test1  test2  test3  test4  test5  test6
3          4  test1  test2  test3  test4  test5  test6
4          5  test1  test2  test3  test4  test5  test6
```

If you want values in `Rows start` as integers rather than strings, chain [`df.astype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data[1:], columns=data[0]).astype({'Rows start': int})
```

Comment: could you pls try this link test data.  https://docs.google.com/document/d/1I_WSeUo37A176C5Ixe_dTt3cE4C8h_keBpBm_V9Nr1s/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I try with this your code but columns are mismatch.

Comment: Just checking to avoid unnecessary headaches: are you allowed to tweak the formatting a little bit. Because for some reason, I think `docx` has difficulty with properly defining rows and columns. This problem disappears if you drag the table from the bottom right a bit inwards, and get the table within the page margin, just as it already is on the left side. After that, it works for me, same as with the dummy table. If do you need this code to be reusable?

Comment: I have a client and data present like last share url. I have run your code. but i wrong format headers.I can't modified user input data.

Comment: Yes, I know. Like I said, with the new table, it has problems with the fact that the table crosses the regular margin. If you correct the margin, it will work. So, question is whether you are allowed/able to do that (e.g. correct it, save file and then run the code), or not? E.g. with the current right margin, `docx` considers 'Study Day\n(Visit Window)' and `'Day –28 to –1'` part of row `1` (i.e. second row), which makes no sense.

Comment: ok could you pls share modified data.

Comment: if it's user input can we modified the file through code. is that posible?

Comment: Tried that, but didn't succeed. I did succeed in getting *this* table in the correct form as a `df`, so I can add that to the A if you want, but I don't think it will be of use if you need this to be reusable. The orig. table is quite a mess, and as mentioned, `docx` doesn't interpret it as one might think. E.g. it thinks there are *12* cols x 26 rows. But it is *11* x 26. If I extract all `cell.text`, I end up with `289` cells (288/12 = 24). At the end there's an extra "X", which you don't actually see in the file itself! Anyway, like I said: I can get you *this result*, if you want.